# C/C++: using a typedef'd function pointer to *declare* a function

Tags: c++, c

I need to typedef a function pointer type to create an array of pointers, *and* to declare a large number of functions that will end up in the array. However, I can't find a way to do both of these things at the same time: either I can get pointers for the array, or I can declare functions, but not both.

Any ideas on how I can get this code to work without lots of pointless text, or am I stuck with repeating the entire function signature for every function I need to declare? Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// declare a fn ptr type named 'myfunc'
typedef void (*myfunc)(int);

//myfunc A,B,C,etc;  **doesn't work, because of the (*)
void A(int);         // does work, but becomes very tedious

int main() {
   myfunc B = A;     // actually assigning a large 2D array
   A(42);
   B(43);
}

void A(int foo) {
   printf("%d\n", foo);
}
```

Comment: It might be easier using __#define__ ; must it be __typedef__ ?

Comment: Not possible. AFAIK, that's explicitly mentioned in either "The C Programming Language" or the C standard. A reason is also given there.

Comment: What happens if you use `typedef void (myfunc)(int);` ?

Comment: #define is bad; it ignores namespaces, renames local variables and member function which accidentaly happen to have same name, etc. - silently without any warning.

Comment: C or C++, which is it?

Comment: @RH: C++, but a C answer would do, if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do

```
using myfunc = void (int);

myfunc A, B, C, etc;
```

And for pointer function:

```
myfunc* f = A;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73fd4129149eb466)

Comment: This does not work with the C language and the OP has tagged the question with the C language also.

Answer (score 4):

In C++ you may use

```
std::remove_pointer_t<myfunc> A, B, C;
```

Or declare one typedef for the function type and another for the pointer to function type:

```
typedef void myfunc(int);
typedef myfunc * myfuncptr;
myfunc A, B, C;
```

The latter works in C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

The standard is pretty clear about disallowing this (from [[dcl.fct]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct#12)):

> A typedef of function type may be used to declare a function but shall not be used to define a function (8.4). *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> typedef void F();
> F fv;              // OK: equivalent to void fv();
> F fv { }           // ill-formed
> void fv() { }      // OK: definition of fv
> ```
>
> *—end example ]*

In your case, you can write:

```
using F = std::remove_pointer_t<myfunc>;
F A, B, C;
```

But you'd still have to use the normal function declarator to define those functions, so that won't accomplish much besides being cryptic.

Comment: i don't actually want to define the function (here): just declare it so that it can be used in the array assignment. The problem is that a typedef of function *pointer* type cannot be used to declare a function, notwithstanding the `remove_pointer_t` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can *declare* a (member) function using a typedef:

```
typedef int F(int);
F f; // declare a function

int main() { f(1); } // and call it
```

But you cannot *define* it using the typedef.